# TIFFDirectory.getAsMetadata() is not including GeoTIFFTagSet. Any solution to this problem? -- JAI

Tags: raster, java, geotiff-tiff, metadata, jai

The source code appears to simply copy the TagSet List object to the IFD and then the TIFFMetadata. I don't understand where it is losing the tagset as it is in the list before the call.

Anyone encountered this problem and have any ideas?

relevant source code:

https://github.com/dcm4che/jai-imageio-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sun/media/imageio/plugins/tiff/TIFFDirectory.java

https://github.com/dcm4che/jai-imageio-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageMetadata.java